# How to pre fill JavaScript array with random values

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var thisarrayshouldbe = 5;
```

How to pre-fill random values from "cars" array and produce new array ?

Comment: Is it possibe to repeat elements? How many items you need to insert?

Comment: both are different values .. in the simple example I provided output array is 3 items ... I need to be 5 items
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> random values from `cars` *[...]* array is 3 items ... I need to be 5 items

Sounds like you just want to run a random number generator five times, where the random number generator can give `0`, `1` or `2`

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

function random_int(max, min) { // max, min inclusive
    min = min | 0; // coerce to int32
    max = max | 0;
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}
// so random_int(2) will produce a value from 0, 1, 2

var i, // iterating variable
    arr = []; // the array being generated

for (i = 4; i >= 0; --i) { // 4 is biggest index in arr length 5
    arr[i] = cars[random_int(cars.length - 1)];
}

// and look at what we've made
arr; // example output: ["Volvo", "Saab", "Saab", "BMW", "Volvo"]
```

Comment: works as expected on console log under the comment I am typing ... just the last part confuses me (and remind me of coffescript) ... I would appreciate more browser friendly version
Thank you

Comment: @Radoslav it's vanilla _JavaScript_, which browser is having trouble with it? Or do you mean it'd be easier to understand as a `for` loop rather than a `while` loop?

Comment: Yes Paul, easier please ... sorry and thank you again :)

Comment: @Radoslav I've edited it to a `for` loop instead, and added in curly braces if you find it makes it easier to read - I kept it looping downwards though; this is just my preference because I created the array using a literal; without giving it an initial size